# Show image path in dropzone.js

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading, dropzone.js

Dears 
I am making a project, upload images through drag and drop in dropzone.js plugin.
i want to show uploaded image path so that user can view uploaded images.
Thanks in advance.....
Here is my code of php

```
<?php
session_start();
$image_path = "";
if(!empty($_FILES))
{
    $project_id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){
        //insert file information into db table
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO images (project_id,file_name, file_path) VALUES('".$project_id."','".$fileName."','".$targetFile."')");
        // echo "path===".$targetFile; exit;

        // $image_path = $targetFile;


    }

}
?>




<div class="image_upload_div" style="width: 400px;" >
    <form action="upload-image.php" class="dropzone" style="height: 400px;">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your base_url+$targetFile :)

Comment: Please ask a question, this is a site for asking questions, right? ;)